# Matching Keys in a HashMap

Tags: java, dicom

I am attempting to do the following (in psuedocode):

- Generate HashMapOne that will be populated by results
  found in a DICOM file (the Key was manipulated for matching
  purposes).
- Generate a second HashMapTwo that will be read from a
  text document.
- Compare the Keys of both HashMaps, if a match add the results of
  the value of HashMapOne in a new HashMapThree.

I am getting stuck with adding the matched key's value to the HashMapThree. It always populates a null value despite me declaring this a public static variable. Can anyone please tell me why this may be? Here is the code snippets below:

```
public class viewDICOMTags {

    HashMap<String,String> dicomFile = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
    HashMap<String,String> dicomTagList = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
    HashMap<String,String> Result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Iterator<org.dcm4che2.data.DicomElement> iter = null;
    DicomObject working;
    public static DicomElement element;
    DicomElement elementTwo;
    public static String result;
    File dicomList = new File("C:\\Users\\Ryan\\dicomTagList.txt");

    public void readDICOMObject(String path) throws IOException
    {
        DicomInputStream din = null;
        din = new DicomInputStream(new File(path));
        try {
            working = din.readDicomObject();
            iter = working.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                element = iter.next();
                result = element.toString();
                String s = element.toString().substring(0, Math.min(element.toString().length(), 11));
                dicomFile.put(String.valueOf(s.toString()), element.vr().toString());
            }   
            System.out.println("Collected tags, VR Code, and Description from DICOM file....");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                din.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ignore){
            }

        }
        readFromTextFile();
    }
    public void readFromTextFile() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            String dicomData = "DICOM";
            String line = null;
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dicomList));
            while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                dicomTagList.put(line.toString(), dicomData);
            }
            System.out.println("Reading Tags from Text File....");
            bReader.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.print(e);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.err.print(i);
        }   
        compareDICOMSets();
    }
    public void compareDICOMSets() throws IOException
    {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : dicomFile.entrySet())
        {

            if(dicomTagList.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
                Result.put(entry.getKey(), dicomFile.get(element.toString()));
            System.out.println(dicomFile.get(element.toString()));
        }
        SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(Result.keySet());
        for (String key : keys) { 
               String value = Result.get(key);
               System.out.println(key);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code looks very wrong

```
 Result.put(entry.getKey(), dicomFile.get(element.toString()));
```

If you are trying to copy the key/value pair from HashMapOne, then this is not correct.

The value for each key added to Result will be null, because you are calling `get` method on `Map` interface on dicomFile. `get` requires a key as a lookup value, and you are passing in

```
element.toString()
```

where element will be the last element that was read from your file.

I think you should be using

```
Result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Ok I can make that change, but why is it if I add a println statement in reference to element.toString() outside of readDICOMObject() method, it is always null?

Comment: I like the answer, you are definately right about it. However, one thing: I want to print the results of the value, in the last enhanced for loop:    for( String key : keys ), How can i reference the value that I am matching?

Comment: From what I see, only matched elements will be added to Result. And your   for loop gets each key and then looks up the value for each key. So you have access to the data. But you are printing the key, not the value.

Comment: Ok so the value that matches with the key will be in the HashMap, i guess the only way to tell for sure is if I write it to a text file...